# In every update aptd crashes with TypeError on 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: 16.04, crash, lts, aptdaemon

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04.5 64-bit LTS for quite some time and intend to use it a little bit more. However, recently I noticed I am getting an internal error due to **aptd** every time there is an update.

The executable leading the problem is `/usr/sbin/aptd` and the error title is **aptd crashed with TypeError in DistroUpgrade(): Expected a PackageKitGlib.DistroUpgradeEnum, but got str** Please see the following screenshot for details.

[image]

So far I have tried reinstalling apt, but I am not sure if I did it correctly. I also have many **PPA**s added in my system. How can I get rid of this error and what might be causing it? I can provide more information if needed.

P.S: I also noticed some weird behavior with Variety application, but I do not know if they are related.

Comment: Try opening `Software & Updates` > `Updates` and mark the option at the bottom (Notify me of a ..) to `Never`. Then run in a terminal `sudo rm  /var/crash/*.*` See if this  issue still then occurs

Comment: @doug Thanks for the suggestion. May I ask the reasoning behind this? You think the new Ubuntu edition might be interfering somehow?

Comment: @doug One more thing: How can I force system to do an update? Is it possible by removing a package through `apt-get remove`? I think there is a clever trick for it.

Comment: I would run `journalctl` and look for error messages. I ran into many problems with `variety` and although it is novel it just didn't seem to work well on my system so I removed it. I'm not saying it's the cause of this problem though.

Answer (score 4):

For troubleshooting `aptdaemon` you shouldn't use `apt` but the commandline utility  `aptdcon`.

Eg, to get more information on the `aptdaemon` crash on performing an upgrade, use the `--upgrade-system` together with the debug (`-d`) arguments:

```
sudo aptdcon -d --upgrade-system
```

See the manual page for more information:

```
man aptdcon
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will try it. By the way how can I reproduce the problem? Is it possible to rollback and try updating again for test purposes?

Comment: From manpages: `There isn't any need to be root to run this programme.`. Also the option `--upgrade-system` says: `Upgrade the whole system.` and this seems unclear how it will fix OP's bugs?

Comment: The first command solved the same problem on my Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!